# How to connect a Belkin modem/router to a Thecus N299 NAS server?

Tags: router, nas

For several years I’ve been using a [Thecus N299 NAS server](http://www.thecus.com/product.php?PROD_ID=11) connected to a U.S. Robotics router that had a IP of `192.168.1.x`. My OS is Windows 7 64bits.

A couple of days ago I changed the router with a Belkin router Model F5D8635-4 v1 that has an address (and gateway ?) of `192.168.2.1`.
When I try to configure the NAS (connected to the WAN port) with setup wizard by using a fixed address such as `192.168.2.5` it says LAN1 and LAN2 can’t be in the same segment and forces me to use DHCP in order to complete the setup.

But, when I try to reach the NAS, I’m not able to reach the NAS with the address `192.168.2.5` (`ERR-CONNECT_REFUSED`). If I try to use the LAN port on thecus NAS Thecus wizard doesn't detect the NAS.

Please help me because I need to reach the data I have on the NAS.
I’ve tried to read info on the Thecus forum and it seems that there is conflict with `192.168.2.x` address but I've not understood how to solve practically this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The NAS should be on a LAN interface. Is your computer on the wireless network? If so, I would guess that the default security policy is preventing either uPNP or Multicast traffic (or both) between the WAN and LAN network segments. If not, I would still guess it is the same issue but without needing to explicitly permit cross-zone traffic of the aforementioned types.

According the the online manual, uPNP is disabled by default and you enable it under the UPnP Enabling section on the utilities page - Give that a shot.